# I would like to automate a process of submitting jobs online and collecting job-ids using Python

Tags: python, automation, mechanize

I want to submit a protein sequence online for HMM comparison using HHpred tool and collect its job id so that I can collect the output later and process. But I have 1200 such sequences and I need to automate the process very badly. I tried to use mechanize package in Python but I couldn't understand properly as there is no documentation available.

```
import mechanize
ur = "http://toolkit.tuebingen.mpg.de/hhpred/"
request = mechanize.Request(ur)
response = mechanize.urlopen(request)
forms = mechanize.ParseResponse(response, backwards_compat=False)
print response.code
form = forms[0]
print form

original_text = form["jobid"]
form["jobid"] =     '''MNDKSKNMMKNFIRTFAGLLLAILLILGFFLLVFPKAGDRFLADKKVSTLSAKNLTYAALGDSLTEGVGDATGQGGF    VPLFAKDIENKTDSSVSSQNFGKAGDTSTQIYNRMMKSKKITDGLKKADIITITIGGNDVLKV
IRDNVSKLSSMTEKDFTKPEELYQARVKKLLDKIREDNPKAQIYVLGIYNPFYLNFPELTVMQNVIDSWNTATAGVVSQE    KNTYFIPINDLLYKGSGDKQAVESGSTSDAVSNNLLYTEDHFHPNNVGYQLMADAVFASY
KEVNQK'''
control = form.find_control("jobid")
print control.name, control.value, control.type
control = form.find_control("showres")
print control.name, control.value, control.type
print control.disabled
request2 = form.click("showres")
response2 = mechanize.urlopen(request2)
forms2 = mechanize.ParseResponse(response2, backwards_compat=False)
form2 = forms2[0]
print form2
```

The website http://toolkit.tuebingen.mpg.de/hhpred/ has many input fields but i could see only the "jobid" and "showres" in the control list using 'mechanize' parser. Code above is what i tried to do but its totally incorrect.
I actually want to paste the sequence in the text box and hit on submit and if possible give my own job-id at the bottom. And save the url of the resulting page after hitting submit.
Kindly help me. (I'm using windows)

Comment: Does it have an API you can access more easily programmatically?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but "Joe" ran the mechanize source code through Pydoc: http://joesourcecode.com/Documentation/mechanize0.2.5/

Comment: form = forms[0] Have you tried to see what are in the other forms? (I belive forms[0] is in the top-left corner...)

Comment: Yes forms[0] is not what the control I'm in need of. Other forms have the input sequence control and submit button control. But how do you submit the job and proceed to the next web page? And also note the resulting web address is unique every time you hit submit.

Comment: First don't forget to start your comment with  @Eric Levieil if you want me to see them. Second you have to find which of the forms you want... For submitting you have the form.submit() mechanize function which return a response, probably with an url attached to it.

Comment: @Eric I could resolve the problem, thank you. :)